# Electron - sudo commands

Tags: node.js, electron, sudo

I have a small app for file manipulation. It mostly handles user's file, but it needs an access to macOS files from time to time, hence I need the admin access.

Is there a way to ask user for root access only once, so the whole app has it and the user is not required to type in the password every time the `sudo` command needs to be run?

I've been looking for a nice solution and one is to ask the user for password and store it locally, but using it later is not considered "secure" anymore.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Unfortunately not :(

Answer (score 0):

Electron-sudo provides GUI for admin/root privileges. Install it by

```
npm install electron-sudo
```

The electron code should have,

```
import Sudoer from 'electron-sudo';
 
let options = {name: 'electron sudo application'},
    sudoer = new Sudoer(options);
 
/* Spawn subprocess behavior */
let cp = await sudoer.spawn(
  'echo', ['$PARAM'], {env: {PARAM: 'VALUE'}}
);
cp.on('close', () => {
  /*
    cp.output.stdout (Buffer)
    cp.output.stderr (Buffer)
  */
});
 
/* Exec subprocess behavior */
let result = await sudoer.exec(
  'echo $PARAM', {env: {PARAM: 'VALUE'}}
);
/* result is Buffer with mixed (both stdout and stderr) output */
 
 
/* Usage with Vanila JS */
 
var Sudoer = require('electron-sudo').default;
var sudoer = new Sudoer(options);
sudoer.spawn('echo', ['$PARAM'], {env: {PARAM: 'VALUE'}}).then(function (cp) {
  /*
    cp.output.stdout (Buffer)
    cp.output.stderr (Buffer)
  */
});
```

Official repository is at https://github.com/automation-stack/electron-sudo